# Just read data from a collection without an authenticated user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I store user profiles and in it, I store the total score as a property. I want to list the top 10 scores and present them as a leaderboard.

Authentication is an optional feature which gives write access to the user profiles collection.
The question is what is the best way to create a leaderboard that can be accessed by unauthenticated users as well, but only using the app? (I am planing to implement app check on Firebase as well)

```
These are my rules

 match /users/{userId} {
      allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow delete: if false;
      allow read,create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: I currently save user scores to the collection if the user is authenticated. But if the user is not authenticated I can't read the data.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the necessary code.

Comment: "But if the user is not authenticated I can't read the data." That seems expected given this rules: `allow read,create: if request.auth != null;`

Comment: yeah, but if I allow everyone to read user collection, the entire collection will be public and anyone can read it. Question is what is the most secure way to allow unauthenticated users to read scores and show a leaderboard? maybe I should run a function hourly and generate the leaderboard and make that public. But does app check disallow people not using the app to reach this data if its public read?

Answer (score 1):

1. Dissallow authenticated users or non-authenticated users to read user entries other than their own.
2. Provide a cloud function `onRequest()` to return the calcualted scores.

The function does NOT apply App check by defauly. This way, the function is accessible publicly.

3. How to cache the function's response:

Caching the function's output will avoid constant reads of the collection `users`. Do this by piping the function call through your hosting configuration in `firebase.json`.

`HTTP-GET` call it something like this: `myprojectbla.web.app/getScores`

**firebase.json**

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/getScores",
        "function": "getScores"
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

**Function**

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const db = getFirestore();

// Allow access from everywhere via Cors:
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });

// For App Check only, disabled in your case:
// const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// admin.initializeApp();

exports.getScores = functions
  .runWith({
    memory: "1GB", timeoutSeconds: 540, maxInstances: 1,
  })
  .region("europe-west3")
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {

      // App Check disabled in your case:
      // 
      // const appCheckToken = request.header("X-Firebase-AppCheck");
      // if (!appCheckToken) {
      //   response.statusMessage = "Unauthorized";
      //   response.statusCode = 401;
      //   response.end();
      // }
      //
      // try {
      //   await admin.appCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
      // } catch (err) {
      //   response.statusMessage = "Unauthorized";
      //   response.statusCode = 401;
      //   response.end();
      // }


      // Get users and calculate top 10 scores
      const users = await db.collection("users").get();


      // App / Browser Cache: 60 seconds
      // Server Cache: 55 seconds
      //
      // see https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache
      
      response.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=60, s-maxage=55");
      response.statusCode = 200;
      response.end( /* ... your top 10 scores... */);
    });
  });
```